# .BAT To .SH Converting?

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file, sh

Well I've written a bat file which is used to load my pokemon backups for when I'm away from my gameboys, however I've converted to linux and I'm having issues getting the .BAT file in my exe (I've decompiled the exe back the the source) to work as a .SH and I can't really find much on how to use shell commands as the same function they would be in a BAT file :/ I would also love to know how to set the SH file to load out of the current directory AND run said program in wine.

Here is my .BAT file which works 100% perfectly under windows but refuses to run under wine or a CMD prompt portable under wine

```
`:MENU
CLS

ECHO ============= RawX GBA's =============
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO 1.  Pokemon Crystal
ECHO 2.  Pokemon Green
ECHO 3.  Pokemon Gold
ECHO 4.  Pokemon Pikachu
ECHO 5.  Pokemon Ruby
ECHO 6.  Pokemon Chaos Black
Echo 7.  Pokemon Silver
ECHO 8.  Pokemon White (NDS)
ECHO 9.
Echo 10.
Echo 11.
Echo 12. Pokemon Black (NDS)
ECHO ==========PRESS 'Q' TO QUIT==========
ECHO.
color fc

SET INPUT=
SET /P INPUT=Please select a number:

IF /I '%INPUT%'=='1' GOTO Selection1
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='2' GOTO Selection2
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='3' GOTO Selection3
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='4' GOTO Selection4
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='5' GOTO Selection5
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='6' GOTO Selection6
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='7' GOTO Selection7
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='8' GOTO Selection8
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='9' GOTO Selection9
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='10' GOTO Selection10
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='11' GOTO Selection11
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='12' GOTO Selection12
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='Q' GOTO Quit

CLS

ECHO ============INVALID INPUT============
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO Please select a number from the Main
echo Menu [1-9] or select 'Q' to quit.
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO ======PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE======

PAUSE > NUL
GOTO MENU

:Selection1

:1
".\VisualBoyAdvance.exe"  ".\Pokemon Crystal.zip"
goto menu

:Selection2

:2
".\VisualBoyAdvance.exe"  ".\Pokemon Green.zip"
goto menu

:Selection3

".\VisualBoyAdvance.exe"  ".\Pokemon Gold.zip"
goto menu

:Selection4

".\VisualBoyAdvance.exe"  ".\Poke'mon Pikachu.zip"
goto menu

:Selection5

".\VisualBoyAdvance.exe"  ".\Pokemon Ruby.zip"
goto menu

:Selection6

".\VisualBoyAdvance.exe"  ".\Pokemon - Chaos Black.zip"
goto menu

:Selection7

".\VisualBoyAdvance.exe"  ".\Pokemon Silver.zip"
goto menu


:Selection8

".\desmume.exe"  ".\PokeWhite.zip"
goto menu

:Selection12

".\desmume.exe"  ".\PokeBlack.zip"
goto menu






:Quit
CLS

ECHO ==============THANK YOU===============
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO ======PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE======

PAUSE>NUL
EXIT`
```

Comment: It's useless on Linux. You should write it from scratch.

Comment: I thought about that, but I really know almost nothing about shell scripting, I've been kinda curious though couldn't I write it in python?

Comment: Yes, you can use Python.

Comment: :) Alright thank you sir, I shall just do that. Does this site allow one ups? or however it works if not Thanks again for the speedy replies

Comment: You'd want to switch to Python if you had plans to make it a lot more complex, but if it just needs to be a straight translation, shell script is more than sufficient for the task. As for "one ups", I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean a way to upvote a comment or answer, that's covered on this site's [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about). As I write this, your question has two downvotes, likely because you're basically asking us to rewrite your script for you, which isn't a clear, specific question. Luckily for you, I was bored enough today to do it anyway. :)

Answer (score 21):

The conversion to Bourne shell is pretty straightforward:

1. Add `#!/bin/sh` or similar as the first line, to tell Linux which interpreter to use. Unlike on Windows, there's more than one command shell, and more script interpreters than just shells besides.
2. The equivalent of the `cmd.exe` command `CLS` is `clear` on Linux.
3. Linux is case-sensitive, so all your `ECHO`s have to be lowercase. If I'd kept your `IF` statements in the translated version, they'd have to be lowercase, too.
4. `echo` in shell scripts doesn't just print everything literally to the end of the line, as in `cmd.exe`. Bourne shell is a much richer language: it can apply meaning to what appears after a command before sending it to the command. In your code, the single quotes (`'`) and multiple spaces won't survive this command processing.

   To avoid problems of this sort, I've double-quoted all of your `echo` strings. I could have done it selectively, double-quoting only the problem strings, but chose to double-quote everything for consistency. I don't want you to get the mistaken idea that `echo` in Bourne shell *requires* the double-quotes.

   If I wasn't interested in keeping the translation simple, so you can see more 1:1 correspondences between batch files and shell scripts, I'd replace the two big blocks of `echo` commands with a [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).
5. `echo.` is just `echo` in Bourne shell. You don't need the dot in Bourne shell because `echo` in Bourne shell isn't overloaded to turn command echoing on and off, as with `ECHO ON/OFF` in `cmd.exe`. (Bourne shell does have a similar feature, enabled via `set -x`.)
6. It is possible to get colored output in Bourne shell, but there is no simple built-in command for it as in `cmd.exe`. If you want pretty colored menus, you can replace much of the code in this script with a call to [`dialog(1)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_(software)).
7. You use `read` to get input in a shell script; `set` does other things.
8. There is no `goto` in Bourne shell. We don't need it, because Bourne shell has decent control structures. I think [a `case` statement](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/The_case_statement) expresses the intent of your inner selection code, and [an infinite `while` loop](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-infinite-loop/) expresses the outer "keep doing this until they hit `q`" scheme.
9. I don't see how code flow gets to your "press any key to continue" bit at the end, so I removed it. If I'm wrong, the rough equivalent of `PAUSE` is `read -n 1 -s`.
10. I have changed the calls to the external programs, dropping the `.exe` and changing `.\` to `./` to match the way things are done on Linux. You still need to come up with Linux equivalents of `VisualBoyAdvance.exe` and `desmume.exe`.

The result looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
clear

while true do
    echo "============= RawX GBA's ============="
    echo "-------------------------------------"
    echo "1.  Pokemon Crystal"
    echo "2.  Pokemon Green"
    echo "3.  Pokemon Gold"
    echo "4.  Pokemon Pikachu"
    echo "5.  Pokemon Ruby"
    echo "6.  Pokemon Chaos Black"
    echo "7.  Pokemon Silver"
    echo "8.  Pokemon White (NDS)"
    echo "9."
    echo "10."
    echo "11."
    echo "12. Pokemon Black (NDS)"
    echo "==========PRESS 'Q' TO QUIT=========="
    echo

    echo -n "Please select a number: "
    read input

    case $input in
        1)
            ./VisualBoyAdvance "Pokemon Crystal.zip"
            ;;

        2)
            ./VisualBoyAdvance "Pokemon Green.zip"
            ;;

        # etc.

        q)
            clear
            exit

        *)
            clear
            echo "============INVALID INPUT============"
            echo "-------------------------------------"
            echo "Please select a number from the Main"
            echo "Menu [1-12] or select 'Q' to quit."
            echo "-------------------------------------"
            echo "======PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE======"
    esac
done
```